# What to do if international student exchange supervisor doesn't answer my email?

Tags: email, international-students, student-exchange

I am applying for an exchange program in Romania next semester. The teacher in Romania sent a research topic one month ago to my teacher (So I guess they both found an agreement and I should be able to go?). I am now expected to do most of the rest . So I sent a first e mail asking for more information about that topic as the research topic has to be accepted by professors and lectors at our university. A few days later I sent him another e-mail specifying exactly who I was as it may have been unclear in my first e-mail. Its now been one week and still received no answer.

What should I do? Keep waiting until I maybe don‘t receive an answer? What would be a good way to deal with that type of situations?

Comment: Also see [What does it mean if a professor does not answer your email in time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24285/what-does-it-mean-if-a-professor-does-not-answer-your-email-in-time)

Comment: Also see [My new advisor didn't reply to my email, is it a sign that she doesn't care?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28335/my-new-advisor-didnt-reply-to-my-email-is-it-a-sign-that-she-doesnt-care)

Comment: Also see [How to get people to reply to emails and what to make of a no response?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45616/how-to-get-people-to-reply-to-emails-and-what-to-make-of-a-no-response)

Comment: Also see [Is ignoring emails acceptable in academia?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/is-ignoring-emails-acceptable-in-academia)

Comment: Also see [What can I do when my e-mails to professors go unanswered?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/75998/what-can-i-do-when-my-e-mails-to-professors-go-unanswered)

Comment: Who is "your teacher" in the second sentence? Is she from your local university? Please clarify.

Comment: @henning yes he is from my university.

Answer (score 2):

Professors are often very busy and receive many emails, sometimes more than a hundred a day. It is not uncommon that an email gets forgotten, especially if it was sent from a stranger. Since a week has passed, it is certainly appropriate to send another polite reminder. However, other strategies might be more effective:

- Ask your local teacher about the issue or ask her to contact the Romanian teacher, explaining that you could not get a response although the issue is urgent.
- Write an email to the Romanian supervisor's secretary/the secretary of the institute.
- Call them on the phone

When writing email, make sure that the issue can already be understood from reading the subject line.