# Decision time after Post-doctoral interview

Tags: interview

I had an interview exactly two weeks ago for a postdoctoral position and my interview went extremely well with the PI. I was told that he'll get back to me in a week after interviewing other candidates, it's been two weeks, I mailed him last week enquiring about the same and he replied he's busy and ***'he'll complete the application process this week'***. I don't know what that means but tomorrow would be one week since he sent that message. I'm getting desperate since I dont have any other offers and I want this badly. Please let me know if should mail him again ? And how long does it usually take?

Comment: This will depend entirely on the person making the decision. Since you don't have any other offers, there's not much you can do besides wait and keep applying elsewhere in case the decision is no.

Comment: @Jay N  There are many similar questions here and you can read the answers to those.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get people to reply to emails and what to make of a no response?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45616/how-to-get-people-to-reply-to-emails-and-what-to-make-of-a-no-response)

Comment: Please check our [archives](https://www.google.com/search?q=Decision+time+after+Post-doctoral+interview+site:academia.stackexchange.com); you are not the first to have this problem. But ultimately, this comes down to the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

> He'll complete the application process this week

Hiring a post-doc requires extensive documentation.

Since it is vacation time and yes, professors are extremely busy persons. Most probably (according to my intuition and experience), he has accepted you for the position. However, the application procedure, documentation and bureaucracy takes some time to complete, especially in this period of the year when admin staff and dean are not in the office regularly. The procedure to complete application process also varies university to university and country to country. For example, in China, in this time of the year, completing the application process takes 1-2 months. On contrary, the whole procedure takes 1-2 weeks during regular term.

I suggest you to be patient and kill your time in some other healthy activities. You'll get the good news soon :)
It is recommended not to bother him by asking about the application status.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's been 20 days since the interview,  I had applied only through my resume and cover letter and I'm not sure how the application process would start without original degree certificates and references. But I'm hopeful and I'll wait for few more days.